# Animation keyframes % are not corrrectly running

Tags: css, animation

```
.shimmer {
  width: 211px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shimmer::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 65%;
  width: 45%;
  left: -75px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black, 50%, transparent);
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
  animation-duration: 100s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    left: -75px;
  }
  5% {
    left: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 20px;
  }
}
```

I need to run an animation on my ::before element at a certain time. I have used Javascript to input the animation name in to the head.

```
var styleElem = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));
styleElem.innerHTML = ".shimmer::before {animation-name:test ;}"
```

When the function runs I need the animation to start and finish within 1 second and then repeat  after every 100seconds. 
To test the speed etc I wanted this to finish at 5% (as the animation only needs to be roughly 1 second) Then it will wait (hidden) so when the 100s is up it's time to run again.

The javascript works fine and the animation starts. The issue is, the keyframes % are not taken into account it will just animating over 100 seconds? what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
0%{
```

left:-75px;

};

Semi colon here was the issue!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Set 200px at 100% point:

```
100% {left: 200px;}
```